# close batch file after execution in java

Tags: java, windows, spring-mvc, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a bat file and running it. Once execution is complete, bat file should close.

```
String cmd = "cmd /c start" + " "+"java -jar batchfilepath"+" "+"\n exit";

Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = r.exec(cmd);
```

Issue- I am able to close the bat file but it closes before execution completes.

I tried following ways

```
1.if(p.waitfor()==0)
{rt.exec("taskkill /IM cmd.exe");}
2.cmd /c start \wait  
3.cmd /k start \wait 
4.processBuilder
```

Help me on this.

Comment: add `pr.waitFor();` ...

Comment: I tried tat too. didnt worked

Comment: there is literally no need to use platform-specific scriptlanguages in order to load jarfiles : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/jarclassloader.html
This is Java, using platform-specific code pretty much defeats the whole concept of it and makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add /wait to wait for the entire execution  to complete and then close the batch file.

Try this. Hope this works

cmd /c start" + " "+"/wait"+"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with a java.jar file in windows.

The batch file:

```
@echo off
cd  C:\NetbeansProject\
java -jar MP2ways.jar
```

End of the program after data displayed, added:

```
   System.out.println("\n Hit Return to exit... ");
   String kS = scan.nextLine();
   System.exit(0);
```

Window closes when hitting return.
(for what it's worth, which ain't much``)